# Extract Data from a Multiple Web Pages into Excel - using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to macros and trying to extract the data from the following webpage into excel. The data from the below link spans to 7 pages (appr 3500 rows). I need this data into my excel work workbook.

http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/hist_stock_result.php?ex=N&sc_id=RI&pno=1&hdn=daily&fdt=2000-01-01&todt=2013-03-01

I have tried web data import feature in excel. But, unable to do that due to unknown reason. Please someone help.....

Comment: Do you want to automate data extraction from this web page to excel with vba or get the data just once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code worked for me. It should get the pages 1-7 from web site and paste each to separate excel sheet.

```
Private Const URL_TEMPLATE As String = "URL;http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/hist_stock_result.php?sc_id=RI&pno={0}&hdn=daily&fdt=2000-01-01&todt=2013-03-01"
Private Const NUMBER_OF_PAGES As Byte = 7

Sub test()
    Dim page As Byte
    Dim queryTableObject As QueryTable
    Dim url As String

    For page = 1 To NUMBER_OF_PAGES
        url = VBA.Strings.Replace(URL_TEMPLATE, "{0}", page)
        Set queryTableObject = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=url, Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.[a1])
        queryTableObject.WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        queryTableObject.WebTables = "3"
        queryTableObject.Refresh
    Next page

End Sub
```

Comment: simply superb.....hats off

Comment: Would u pls help me with below   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994918/getting-external-data-from-web-into-excel-not-working

Comment: @user2063626 i have answered your question: stackoverflow.com/questions/14994918/…

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel...You are awesome...The code works perfect...However, I would like to have the 7 page data in a single worksheet i.e., in Sheet 1...Also, column A should pasted as text...I dont need the last 2 columns i.e., columns G&F (Spread Data) I dont have any prior knowledge in macros...So, I was unable to modify the code....Thanks for the help in advance.....